# Dog growls when I walk inside after being out for a very brief time

Tags: dogs, vocalizations

Four of us in a house (my wife, myself, two young daughters), and we have an almost two-year old, 10 pound Maltipoo (Maltese-Poodle mix). He growls only at me and only under a specific condition: If I step out of the house for a very brief time (less than a minute), he growls and tries to attack me when I come back in.

For example, if I step outside to get the mail or take out the trash, he will be looking out the closed screen door (through the glass). He sees me coming back and as soon as I open the screen door, he gets vicious. Day or night, it doesn't matter.

*However*, if go out and get in my car to go away for a much longer period of time, he's fine. I should note that in this case I also close the inside door. For example, if I happen to go to work, or go to the gym, or go food shopping, everything is fine. Inside the house, he likes to lay down on the sill of our large window that faces the street and our driveway. When he sees the car pull up in the driveway, I can see him jump down. He waits for me to open the door, and is crazy with affection in these cases when I do come in.

More data: I do 99% of all the walking and feeding; dog is a Male; he is intact.

Any ideas as to why he growls only in the situations I described? He doesn't frighten me, but it is disturbing and very annoying.

Comment: Do you smoke or in any other way change your scent when being short times outside? Dogs have fine noses. They smell i.e. smoke or alcohol and may be disturbed by it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why did my dog started growling at one person?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/18830/why-did-my-dog-started-growling-at-one-person)